# /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found, while build image docker

Tags: python, django, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create and run a djanog image with the docker to deploy it along with kubernetes, but when I run the image build command, it gives the error "/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
"

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
LABEL maintainer="r.ofc@hotmail.com"

ENV PROJECT_ROOT /app
WORKDIR $PROJECT_ROOT

RUN apk update \
    && apk add mariadb-dev \
        gcc\
        python3-dev \
        pango-dev \
        cairo-dev \
        libtool \
        linux-headers \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        openssl-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        zlib-dev
        
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

can someone help me?

Comment: The `-slim` images use`apt` AFAIR.

Comment: Hi, i trying, but not fuction. return erro: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

E: Invalid operation add

Comment: why are you installing python3dev? doesnt the image already comes with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `python:3.8-slim` is based on Debian, which is using the apt package manager, not apk.

You can change the image version:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
```

and it should work fine.

Another solution is to keep the `python:3.8-slim` image, but switch to apt:

```
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y libmariadb-dev \
        gcc\
        python3-dev \
        libcogl-pango-dev \
        libcairo2-dev \
        libtool \
        linux-headers-amd64 \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        zlib1g-dev
```

I have updated the package names because they are not the same in Debian.

Comment: thanks you for your help, the packages that are in error appeared, I will search for the updated packages

Comment: No problem, I don't know if you saw it but I updated my answer, you can just keep your initial Dockerfile with `apk add` and switch the image version to `python:3.8-alpine`, it may be easier than changing all packages to match the debian version.

Comment: and really simpler a dns error occurred, I'll check what can be